# React - Event handling on mapped button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, events

Some beginner help please.

I have a simple learning React app where I'm mapping over an array and creating some individual cards based on the items in the Array.

```
const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Mario World",
    Platform: "SNES",
    year: 1992,
    text:
      "Super Mario World is a 1990 side-scrolling platform game developed and published by Nintendo for the Super Nintendo Entertainment System (SNES). ",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Sonic the Hedgehog",
    Platform: "Megadrive",
    year: 1991,
    text:
      "Sonic the Hedgehog[a] is a platform game developed by Sonic Team and published by Sega for the Sega Genesis home video game console. ",
  },
];

export default list;
```

```
import React from "react";

class GameList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showText: false };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({ showText: !this.state.showText });
  };
  render() {
    const listItems = this.props.list.map((item) => (
      <div className="card" key={item.id}>
        <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
        <span>
          <span role="img" aria-label="emoji">
            
          </span>
          {item.Platform}
        </span>
        <span role="img" aria-label="emoji">
           {item.year}
        </span>
        <button
          id={item.id}
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(item.id, e)}
        >
          Info {item.id}
        </button>
        {this.state.showText && <p>{item.text}</p>}
      </div>
    ));
    return <div className="container">{listItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default GameList;
```

I've added a button that I want to display some extra text, specific to the object in the array, when clicked. I managed to add the button but when I click it toggles all array item text not the text specific to the object. I've got the button to console.log the individual id but I don't know how to make it only toggle the specific text, not everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boolean value for showText is being used by all dynamically rendered buttons and hence they all either show the text or don't show it

The solution here is to keep the id of button in showText. If you wish to show extra text for just one button at a time, maintain a string or else maintain an array.

```
import React from "react";

class GameList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showText: ''};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({ showText: id });
  };
  render() {
    const listItems = this.props.list.map((item) => (
      <div className="card" key={item.id}>
        <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
        <span>
          <span role="img" aria-label="emoji">
            
          </span>
          {item.Platform}
        </span>
        <span role="img" aria-label="emoji">
           {item.year}
        </span>
        <button
          id={item.id}
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(item.id, e)}
        >
          Info {item.id}
        </button>
        {(this.state.showText === item.id) && <p>{item.text}</p>}
      </div>
    ));
    return <div className="container">{listItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default GameList;
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.

Comment: One further question, if I may.  I then want to hide the text that has been shown by clicking the button that opened it, should using prevstate to do this?

Comment: You can check for the value before setting it. IF the value in state is the same as the id received as arguments in the function, you would set the value to `''`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here you can create a new `Card` component which holds its own state so each `Card` can show (or not show) the text on its own.

Here is an exemple.
I wrote it using React Functional Components + [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) because I think the syntax is much more easier to use and here it doesn't seem like you need to handle complex life cycle:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Card = ({ item }) => {
  const [shouldShowText, setShouldShowText] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
      <span>
        <span role="img" aria-label="emoji">
          
        </span>
        {item.Platform}
      </span>
      <span role="img" aria-label="emoji">
         {item.year}
      </span>
      <button
        id={item.id}
        type="button"
        onClick={(e) => setShouldShowText(!shouldShowText)}
      >
        Info {item.id}
      </button>
      {shouldShowText && <p>{item.text}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

const GameList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameList;
```